# Map substring of column values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column "Region" where the first two digits of a zip-code can be attributed to a region:

- Zip_code: 11 = Region:A
- Zip_code: 22 = Region:B
- Zip_code: 44 = Region:C

Main table

```
Zip_code      product_id
110034        55454
114242        45445
113564        46454
223434        53533
224535        56455
223435        63535
444345        62435
443535        24353
```

Output Table

```
Zip_code      product_id   Region
110034        55454        A
114242        45445        A 
113564        46454        A
223434        53533        B
224535        56455        B
223435        63535        B
444345        62435        C
443535        24353        C
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided us with sample code of whatever you've implemented or tried to so we can help you with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the `Zip_codes` and map them with a dictionary:

```
df['Region'] = df.Zip_code.astype(str).str[:2].map({'11':'A', '22':'B', '44':'C'})
```

---

```
print(df)
   Zip_code  product_id Region
0    110034       55454      A
1    114242       45445      A
2    113564       46454      A
3    223434       53533      B
4    224535       56455      B
5    223435       63535      B
6    444345       62435      C
7    443535       24353      C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd


#map between first-digits in Zip-Code and Region
regions_map = {11: "A", 22:"B", 44:"C"}

df["Region"] = df["Zip_code"].apply(lambda x: regions_map[int(str(x)[:2])])

print(df)
#   Zip_code  product_id Region
#0    110034       55454      A
#1    114242       45445      A
#2    113564       46454      A
#3    223434       53533      B
#4    224535       56455      B
#5    223435       63535      B
#6    444345       62435      C
#7    443535       24353      C
```